# How can I create a rig where each bone only affects its surrounding mesh?

Tags: rigging

So, I am trying to create a version of Minecraft Steve in blender to use in ue4. Each body part I have made isn't joined to another physically, but they are all one object. I have rigged it, however the weighting seems to affect the entire model not just the surrounding faces. Can I weight it somehow to only move the one part, e.g. the arm and none of the body or head?

[image: Rigging Problem]

[image: Bone layout]

Comment: You can specify which vertices are affected by which bones.  Google "blender attach bone to vertex group"  and there are lots of good tuts out there.  HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

Parent *With Empty Group* instead of *With Automatic Weight*, then in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, assign the selected vertices to the vertex groups they are supposed to be part of (the groups that have the name of the bones that are supposed to control them).

Or select your object, go in *Edit* mode, select all, separate your object in several different objects wit <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*, then back to *Object* mode, select a limb, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, and parent to > *Bone*.

Comment: Thanks, the first option here worked perfectly :)